# Ng Build issues when using Angular 10 project - [An unhandled exception occurred: Job name "..getProjectMetadata" does not exist.]

Tags: angular, angular10

I have an Angular 10 Project which builds successfully locally but fails with the following error when building on jenkins.

```
[error] Error: Job name "..getProjectMetadata" does not exist.
    at Observable._subscribe (/usr/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/src/experimental/jobs/simple-scheduler.js:350:23)
    at Observable._trySubscribe (/usr/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Observable.js:44:25)
    at Observable.subscribe (/usr/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Observable.js:30:22)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/rxjs/internal/util/subscribeTo.js:22:31
    at Object.subscribeToResult (/usr/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/rxjs/internal/util/subscribeToResult.js:10:45)
    at SwitchMapSubscriber._innerSub (/usr/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/switchMap.js:65:54)
    at SwitchMapSubscriber._next (/usr/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/switchMap.js:55:14)
    at SwitchMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (/usr/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Subscriber.js:66:18)
    at SwitchMapSubscriber.notifyNext (/usr/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/switchMap.js:86:26)
    at InnerSubscriber._next (/usr/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/rxjs/internal/InnerSubscriber.js:28:21)
    at InnerSubscriber.Subscriber.next (/usr/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Subscriber.js:66:18)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/rxjs/internal/util/subscribeTo.js:17:28
    at Object.subscribeToResult (/usr/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/rxjs/internal/util/subscribeToResult.js:10:45)
    at SwitchMapSubscriber._innerSub (/usr/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/switchMap.js:65:54)
    at SwitchMapSubscriber._next (/usr/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/switchMap.js:55:14)
    at SwitchMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (/usr/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Subscriber.js:66:18)
```

Below is the output of the ng --version command from my local machine.

```
Angular CLI: 10.0.2
Node: 10.15.3
OS: win32 x64

 

Angular: 10.0.3
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

 

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.1000.2
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.1000.2
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.1000.2
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.1000.2
@angular-devkit/core              10.0.2
@angular-devkit/schematics        10.0.2
@angular/cdk                      10.0.1
@angular/cli                      10.0.2
@angular/material                 10.0.1
@ngtools/webpack                  10.0.2
@schematics/angular               10.0.2
@schematics/update                0.1000.2
rxjs                              6.6.0
typescript                        3.9.6
webpack                           4.43.0
```

Below is the output on the jenkins server when running the above command.

```
Angular CLI: 8.3.19
Node: 13.6.0
OS: linux x64

 

Angular: 10.0.3
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router
 

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.1000.2
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.1000.2
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.1000.2
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.1000.2
@angular-devkit/core              10.0.2
@angular-devkit/schematics        10.0.2
@angular/cdk                      10.0.1
@angular/cli                      10.0.2
@angular/material                 10.0.1
@ngtools/webpack                  10.0.2
@schematics/angular               10.0.2
@schematics/update                0.1000.2
rxjs                              6.6.0
typescript                        3.9.6
webpack                           4.43.0
```

I have heard that the global angular cli version will not impact things like ng build & other tooling after a new project is generated. Also node version should not cause issues. We have few other Angular v9 projects successfully working with the same jenkins server.

Any suggestions or anyone else who is facing the same issues. I would want to solve this & not have to downgrade to version 9.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue to this (wasn't using Jenkins). The thing that worked for me was downgrading to Node version 12.18.2 on the server. Version 13.6.0 caused me problems once I upgraded to angular 10.